# Show log of commits affecting files matching a pattern whose diff also matches a pattern

Tags: git

I want to view a `git log` of commits that obey all of the following:

1. The commit modifies a file whose name matches a given pattern.
2. The commit changes the number of occurrences of a pattern in a file (essentially, what `--pickaxe-regex -S` does).
3. The change matching rule 2 does not necessarily occur in the file matching rule 1.

Basically, I want to combine [Show all commits whose diff contain specific string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18364146/208273) and [Find commits that modify file names matching a pattern in a GIT repository](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6490454/208273).  Just combining those two techniques, as I've done below, satisfies rules 1 & 2, but not 3.

So far I have:

```
git log --pickaxe-regex -S 'ChangePattern|SomeAlternatePattern' -- '*/filename.txt'
```

This works as long as the change occurs in `filename.txt`; however, the change I am looking for is in a different file than the one that is being matched by the pattern.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can combine `git log` and `git show` :

```
# have `git log` just output the hash of selected commits :
git log --format="%H" --pickaxe-regex -S 'ChangePattern|SomeAlternatePattern' |\
  # `git show` will not output anything if commit doesn't modify any of the files
  while read sha; do git show $sha -- '*/filename.txt'; done
```

---

The formatting options for the end output should be added to `git show` :

```
# example :
# '--oneline' : one line per commit
# '-s' : don't output the patch for commit
git show --oneline -s $sha -- '*/filename.txt'
```

If you want to view the modifications that triggered the `-S` condition, you can use `git log` to filter on `'*/filename.txt'` and pass the `-S` filter to `git show` :

```
git log --format="%H" -- '*/filename.txt' |\
  while read sha; do
    git show --pickaxe-regex -S 'ChangePattern|SomeAlternatePattern' $sha
  done
```

Comment: This works even better if you add `--color --stat` to the `git show` arguments and then pipe the whole thing into `less -R`

Comment: `git log --format="%H"` — isn't it just `git rev-list HEAD` ?

Comment: @phd : I found out that `git rev-list` doesn't support `-S` (or any of the other pickaxe options)

Comment: the other way around works though : `git rev-list HEAD -- '*/filename.txt' | while read sha; do git show -S pattern $sha; done`

Comment: It's annoying that there's no `--porcelain` option to `git log`, since we sometimes need to use `git log` as plumbing like this.

Comment: probably this could also be done with `xargs` instead of a loop, so that a single `git show` invocation is used